# Attempt to insert non-property list object for Key

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to store an `NSString` value in `NSUserDefaults`. It takes some UUID-like format (e.g. `7da0b3fd-25ca-42c5-a934-bd89362a016b`) if the user is logged in or `NULL` otherwise.

However **occasionally** my app gets crashed reporting that the data being stored is incompatible with property-list types.

The property is defined as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userId;
```

Here is the code I write this property with:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (self.userId != NULL) {
    [prefs setValue:self.userId forKey:@"UserId"];
} else {
    [prefs setValue:NULL forKey:@"UserId"];
}
[prefs synchronize];
```

And here are the examples of errors being reported:

> Stack Trace: Attempt to insert non-property list object
> `GEOMapService: 0x280c80f00` for key UserId
>
> Stack Trace: Attempt
> to insert non-property list object `GPBEnumDescriptor: 0x28370a480`
> for key UserId
>
> Stack Trace: Attempt to insert non-property list
> object `NWConcrete_nw_protocol_stack: 0x283000800` for key UserId
>
> Stack Trace: Attempt to insert non-property list object `UIImageConfiguration:0x2830f3540 traits=(DisplayScale = 3)` for key UserId
>
> Stack Trace: Attempt to insert non-property list object
> `GEOMapRegion: 0x2838eea00 { eastLng = "-81.86280557675238"; mapRegionSourceType = "REV_POINT_PADDED"; northLat = "28.56967626614077"; southLat = "28.56069311329958"; westLng = "-81.87303376983076"; }` for key UserId

and some other different crashes like this

How to fix this error?

Comment: You can only insert object that conform to `NSCoding` in `NSUserDefaults`. Maybe you are trying to do something like that?

Comment: @Tj3n But Im storing NSString which confirms to NSCoding

Comment: `NULL` however does not. Store it as empty string, or delete the default instead for example.

Comment: Do you use those classes or key `@"UserId"` with `NSUserDefaults` somewhere else in your app?

Comment: Is ARC enabled? If not, is `userId` always initialized?

Comment: Seeing the errors, it seems that `self.userId` is not a `NSString`. Also, you might want to check with `self.userId != nil` instead of `NULL`. You get the error in the `if` or the `else`? If it's the `if`, either the `!= NULL` causes issue, or while you declared the variable as a `NSString`, when assigning it, it's not a `NSString`. To debug, check when you do `userId = something`, and check `[something class]`.